# How do I install dtcwt package?

Tags: python, conda

I typically have a hard time with installation issues. But, I am particularly having more problem with `dtcwt` package because there aren't much "how to" solutions for this package. Can you please help me?

I tried:

```
conda install dtcwt
conda install -c conda-forge dtcwt
```

Comment: "*there aren't much "how to" solutions for this package*" How about the [official documentation's Installation section](https://dtcwt.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.0/gettingstarted.html#installation)?

Comment: the official documentation is not helpful in resolving my issue. It tells me to do the exact thing that led me to have this issue.

Comment: "*It tells me to do the exact thing that led me to have this issue*" The linked documentation explicitly uses `pip` and doesn't make any mention of `conda`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using the following method:

1. I set my terminal location to `site-packages` folder inside the anaconda folder

```
cd <path to site-packages>
```

2. Then I cloned the `dtcwt` github repository

```
git clone https://github.com/rjw57/dtcwt.git
```

3. Next, I set the terminal path to the `dtcwt` folder that was created from step 2.

```
cd <path to dtcwt>
```

4. Then, I ran `setup.py`.

```
python3 setup.py install
```